# How to execute variation trend calculation functions in Apache IoTDB with having condition in query?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I noticed that Apache IoTDB has variation trend calculation functions like `TIME_DIFFERENCE` and `DIFF` to calculate data results based on time dimension. I want to know can these variation trend calculation functions be used with `HAVING` condition query, so I can check the results based on time and certain range conditions (for example between certain values)? I checked the official guide and the example query statement did not include any example with `HAVING`.

Answer (score 0):

The variation trend calculation function is not identified as an aggregate function in Apache IoTDB. `having` can only perform secondary filtering on the results of the aggregate function, so it cannot be used with variation trend calculation function at this point. However, IoTDB is developing UDAF. If some variation trend calculation functions are aggregate functions later (that is, multiple rows of data become one row), UDAF can also be used. After achieving UDAF, you can use `having` with variation trend calculation functions.